# decimal string to Integer value in Java

Tags: java

```
public Customer(Hashtable<String,String> data) {
        this.recordNum = Integer.parseInt(new DecimalFormat("#").format(Double.parseDouble(data.get("Record #"))));
}
```

data is Hashtable<String,String>.

data.get("Record #")
This is a part of my class constructor. I wonder if there is cleaner code to handle a string value that is decimal in Java.

Comment: For me, it is unclear what the code is supposed to do. Can you [edit] the post and clarify what the actual requirement is?

Comment: @Turning85 cleaner code to handle a string value that is decimal in Java.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add the clarification. Also, why do you parse the `String` as `Double` initiallly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Customer(Hashtable<String,String> data) {
    this.recordNum = Double.valueOf(data.get("Record #")).intValue();}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parseDouble` from the Double class which accepts a String argument and cast to an int

```
this.recordNum = (int) Double.parseDouble(data.get("Record #"));
```

from g01d's comment

Comment: ... and will fail if the value is not an integer. This code does not have the same semantics as the code provided in the question.

Comment: No reason you can't parse a double instead and cast it to an int.

Comment: If I do this, I get java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.0"

Comment: You're saying `double val = Double.parseDouble("1.0")` throws an exception? Are you sure about your input?

Comment: @g0ld I edited my answer after his comment.

Comment: @g01d I think the comment of OP related to the 1st revision of the answer, where `Integer.parseInt(...)` was used. This is exactly the scenario I mentioned in my [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67375141/decimal-string-to-integer-value-in-java?noredirect=1#comment119088547_67375205).